# Looking for Word Sequences Inside of a String

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list

Haven't seen anyone solving something similar to this without using regex. So I have a text = "I have three apples because yesterday I bought three apples" and the list of key words: words = ['I have', 'three', 'apples', 'yesterday'] and k = 2. I have write to a function that finds and returns word sequences of >= k 'words' (by words I mean word combinations identified as a single element in the list e.g. 'I have' is considered a word).

In this case, it should return ['I have three apples', 'three apples']. Even though 'yesterday' is in the string, it's < k, so it doesn't match.

I'm assuming there needs to be a stack to keep track of the size of the sequences. I started writing the code without 1) it doesn't work in this situation because I try checking 'i have', then 'i have three' etc and it can't identify just 'three apples'; 2) I don't know how to proceed with it. Here's the code:

```
text = "I have three apples because yesterday I bought three apples"
words = ['I have', 'three', 'apples', 'yesterday']
k = 2

check1 = []


def search(text, words, k):
    for i in words:
        finding = text.count(i)
        if finding != 0:
            check1.append(i)
            check2 = ' '.join(check1)
            
            occurrences = text.count(check2)
            if occurrences > 0:
                #i want to check if the previous number of occurrences was the same 
                #that's why I think I need a stack. if it is, i keep going
                #if it's not, i append the previous phrases to the list if they're >= k and keep 
                #checking
                pass
            else:
                #the next word doesn't belong to the sequence, so we finish the process
                #by adding the right number of word sequences >= k to the resulting list
                pass
        else:
            #the word is not in the list and I need to add check2 to the list 
            #considering all word sequences
            pass
```

Different ways of solving this or any ideas are very much appreciated because I'm stuck on trying to solve it this way and I don't know how to implement it.

Comment: Does the order matter? For example, what should be the result for "How many apples do I have?" ?

Comment: @PM77-1 yes, unfortunately, it does. So that it can only be 'three apples', not 'apples three'. The result for your example would be an empty list because just 'apples' and 'I have' are less than k

Comment: Sorry. Here's a better example, "Is three apples all I have?".

Comment: @PM77-1 here it would return ['three apples']. If somehow it was "Is three apples all I have three", then it would return ['three apples', 'I have three']

Comment: You could transform the list of words to a graph with directed edges, indicating the words that are allowed to follow. Then, you just walk this graph, based on the input string and record the allowed paths you walked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution by walking through the text, noting the words in the correct order. The complexity of this algorithm increases quickly with the length of your word list and the length of text, however. Depending on the application, you might want to do it differently:

```
def walk(t,w,k):
    t+=' '
    node = -1
    current = []
    collection = []
    while len(t)>1:
        elong = False
        for i in range(len(w)):
            if i > node and t[:len(w[i])] == w[i]:
                    node = i
                    t = t[len(w[i])+1:]
                    current.append(w[i])
                    elong=True
        if not elong or len(t)<2:
            t = t[t.find(' ')+1:]
            if len(current)>=k: collection.append(' '.join(current))
            current = []
            node = -1
    return collection
```

This function would handle the requests you mentioned in the question as follows:

```
#Input:
print(walk("I have three apples because yesterday I bought three apples",
           ['I have', 'three', 'apples', 'yesterday'],
           2))

#Output:
['I have three apples', 'three apples']

#Input:
print(walk("Is three apples all I have three",
           ['I have', 'three', 'apples', 'yesterday'],
           2))

#Output:
['three apples', 'I have three']
```

It heavily relies on there being blanks that separate the words and would not cope well with punctuation. You might want to include some preprocessing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It helped me a lot with the problem. I fixed the problem with repetitions though because if the input is `text = 'I have apples but no oranges I I I have I have apples and pears', 
words = ['I have', 'apples', 'and', 'pears'], 
k = 2`, the output is `['I have apples', 'apples and pears']`, so it loses the second 'I have' along the way. Briefly speaking, I fixed it by checking after while len(t)>1 that if len(current) = 1, current[0] doesn't equal to the next word in t. Thank you again!